# How to select elements from UNION operation in sqwrl query

Tags: owl, ontology, reasoning, swrl

I am able to select the size of s3 and it is giving me the correct answer in rule 1. However, I want to select all the elements in s3. I tried Rule 2 but it is giving me the exception "error running SQWRL queries: error running Drools rule engine"

My goal is to retrieve all the diseases that have either symptom vomiting OR fever. Any help will be highly appreciated.

### Rule 1:

```
Symptom(fever) ^ Symptom(vomiting) ^ Disease(?x) ^ Disease(?y) ^ has_symptom(?x, fever) ^ has_symptom(?y, vomiting)˚sqwrl:makeSet(?s1, ?x) ^ sqwrl:makeSet(?s2, ?y)˚sqwrl:union(?s3, ?s1, ?s2) ^ sqwrl:size(?n, ?s3) -> sqwrl:select(?n)
```

### Rule 2:

```
Symptom(fever) ^ Symptom(vomiting) ^ Disease(?x) ^ Disease(?y) ^ has_symptom(?x, fever) ^ has_symptom(?y, vomiting)˚sqwrl:makeSet(?s1, ?x) ^ sqwrl:makeSet(?s2, ?y)˚sqwrl:union(?s3, ?s1, ?s2) -> sqwrl:select(?s3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SQWRLCollections#retrieving-all-elements-from-a-collection), you should try to use the binary built-in predicate `sqwrl:element(?e, ?sd)` with the first element argument `?e` beeing unbound, i.e.:

```
Symptom(fever) ^ Symptom(vomiting) ^ Disease(?x) ^ Disease(?y) ^
has_symptom(?x, fever) ^ has_symptom(?y, vomiting) ^ 
sqwrl:makeSet(?s1, ?x) ^ sqwrl:makeSet(?s2, ?y) ^ sqwrl:union(?s3, ?s1, ?s2) ^
sqwrl:element(?e, ?s3)  
-> sqwrl:select(?e)
```